# docker: Error response from daemon: network mysql_net not found

Tags: mysql, linux, docker

I'm running this command in Docker `docker run --restart always --network mysql_net --ip 192.169.0.2 --name mariadb -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -v mariadb:/var/lib/mysql -d mariadb`

But I'm getting this error : docker: Error response from daemon: network mysql_net not found.

I've been looking for info for a while now but due to I'm starting in Docker and i didn't find any info I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the network `mysql_net` does not exists yet. You can create e.g. `bridge network` as follows:

```bash
docker network create -d bridge mysql_net
```

But I recommend you starting it with `docker-compose`. See in [official docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb) page of e.g. mariadb for docker-compose example.